# Adding trigram index to Postgres table in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg-trgm

Postgres allows for trigram indices with the [pg_trgm module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html).

Here's the example code they provide in the "Index Support" section:

```
CREATE TABLE test_trgm (t text);
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON test_trgm USING GIST (t gist_trgm_ops);
```

Here is the migration I came up with:

```
class AddTitleTrigramIndexToContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
     enable_extension 'pg_trgm'
     execute "CREATE INDEX contacts_title_trigram_ix ON contacts USING GIST (title gist_trgm_ops);"
  end
end
```

Is there a better way to add this migration?  I'm not even sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 11):

According to this [unit test](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4734812ec595aa1a3951acc646d3b304fe7f0098/activerecord/test/cases/adapters/postgresql/active_schema_test.rb#L62-L63) the index can be added like this:

```
add_index :contacts, :title, using: :gist, opclass: {title: :gist_trgm_ops}
```

Comment: NOTE: `opclass` option requires Rails 5.2+

Comment: NOTE: if you get `PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  data type character varying has no default operator class for access method "gist"` error when doing the migration add. `enable_extension 'btree_gist'` before the `add_index` method

Comment: Spot on, as shown in https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index